# Wicket RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException

Tags: java, spring, wicket

I have problems with my Web Application based on Spring and Wicket. I have encountered problem with session timeout, and I modify my WicketApplication.java with the following lines of code

```
   getApplicationSettings().setPageExpiredErrorPage(LoginPage.class);
    getPageSettings().setRecreateBookmarkablePagesAfterExpiry(false);
```

When I deploy in my Tomcat server, and the session expire, the application launch an exception org.apache.wicket.RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException and the Tomcat server give me this error

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [] threw exception
org.apache.wicket.RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException
```

Anyone can give me help?

Comment: I believe you need to use some listener to handle this session expiry .

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint at `org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack#execute()` in the `catch` clause and see why it is not handled by Wicket.

Comment: Where can I insert the try clause?